# problema de AJAX al recorrer un JSON

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql, ajax

Estoy haciendo un proyecto y estoy usando jQuery para ajax quiero implementar una tabla con esta tecnología pero a la hora de listarla me da varios comportamientos extraños

```
**función que carga los datos de la tabla**
    /*CARGAR TABLA DE TABLA MATERIA PRIMA*/
        function cargarTabla(){
            $('#tabla_materia_prima').empty();

            $.getJSON("./cargarDatos.php", function(registros){

                var datos = [];
                console.log(registros);

                $.each(registros, function(indice,valor){
                    
                    if(indice > 0){
                        let plantilla = "<tr>";
                            
                            plantilla+= "<td>"+ valor.correlativo +"</td>";
                            plantilla+= "<td>"+ valor.id_usuario +"</td>";
                            plantilla+= "<td>"+ valor.codigo +"</td>";
                            plantilla+= "<td>"+ valor.precio +"</td>";
                            plantilla+= "<td>"+ valor.cantidad +"</td>";
                            plantilla+= "<td>"+ valor.precio_subtotal +"</td>";
                            plantilla+= "<td>"+ valor.numero_factura +"</td>";
                            plantilla+= "<td class='textcenter'><button class='btn btn-outline-danger' onclick='EliminarMateriaPrima("+valor.correlativo+")'><i class='bi bi-trash' style='font-size: 20px;'></i>Eliminar</button></td>";
                            plantilla+= "</tr>";

                            
                            datos.push(plantilla);

                    }
                });
                console.log(datos);

                $('#tabla_materia_prima').append(datos.join(""));

            });
        }
```

**Archivo php**

```
   <?php
    
        require "../conexion.php";
    
        session_start();
    
        $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM comp_materia_temp");
    
        $arreglo = mysqli_fetch_array($consulta);
    
        echo json_encode($arreglo);
    
    ?>
```

[image: lo que muestra la consola por si a alguien le otorga mas información]

entiendo que al usar mysqli_fetch_array me va a devolver índice y asociación en la lista, pero como tal no entiendo muy bien como mostrar los datos del JSON en la tabla, si tienen alguna sugerencia o blog que me pudiera interesar agradecería su ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que debes hacer es usar [mysqli_fetch_assoc()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) para obtener solo un arreglo asociativo y no agregar información innecesaria a la petición y, además, debes recorrer todos los resultados, porque estás leyendo solo uno:

```
<?php
    require "../conexion.php";
    session_start();
    $consulta = mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT * FROM comp_materia_temp");
    // Inicializa la el arreglo
    $arreglo = [];
    // Crea un ciclo para leer todos los resultados
    while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($consulta)) {
        // Inserta cada fila en el arreglo
        $arreglo[] = $fila;
    }
    echo json_encode($arreglo);
?>
```

Con esto ya debería funcionar el código Javascript, solo omitiendo el primer elemento por ese `if(indice > 0)`